# Gitlab CI - демонстрационный сервер для каждой сборки

Tags: docker, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-runner, cd

Есть типичный frontend репозиторий, мастер ветка автоматически разворачивается на прод сервер

Хочется, чтобы при пуше в любую из веток в контейнере происходила сборка проекта(понятно как добиться) и собранная сборка автоматически "сервилась", то есть запускалась на каком-то адресе и в нее можно было потыкать хотя бы 10-15 минут после запуска pipeline

Gitlab CE, standalone, раннеры свои, на данный момент обычные докер контейнеры. Вопрос в том, как научить раннера раздавать наружу сборку

P.S. формулировки очень кривые, как сформулировать яснее - без понятия, поэтому буду рад любым уточняющим вопросам

Comment: нужно кастомные ветки разворачивать куда-нибудь со внушней ссылкой, чтобы туда потыкать можно было. так?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor да!

Comment: у вас есть сервер, чтобы деплоить кастомные бранчи?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor прям сервер-сервер? есть, но это чуть не то. Вдруг будет два одновременных билда разных веток

Comment: вам же надо публиковать продукт куда-то. если нет сервера, то куда вы хотите публиковать? на прод ведь не будете заливать?

Comment: предположим у вас есть сервер.  на нем нужно развернуть касотмные бранчи. если все кастомные бранчи известны (например develop, release) вы настраиваете nginx на то, что по урлу `/develop` будет смотреть на `localhost:8888`, а по `/release` будет смотреть на `localhost:9999`. при деплоя контейнера, вы прокидываете для develop бранча нужный порт. обращаетесь к серверу как `http://myserver.com/develop` и у вас нужная версия продукта.  как вам такой вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как бы я реализовывал:

- docker swarm server
- добавить wildcard A запись *.domain.com
- Traefik (легко динамически добавлять правила, что и требуется + ssl letencrypt из коробки + wildcard cert)

  ```
  version: '3.2'
  services:
    frontend:
      image: "${REGISTRY}/${FRONTEND_SERVICE}:${FRONTEND_SERVICE__VERSION}{{env}}" 
      depends_on:
        - traefik
      networks:
        - proxy
      healthcheck:
        test: 'nc -z localhost 80 > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 1'
      deploy:
        mode: replicated
        labels:
          traefik.enable: 'true'
          traefik.docker.network: '{{ inventory_hostname }}_proxy'
          traefik.backend: frontend
          traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method: drr
          traefik.frontend.rule: "Host: ${GIT_COMMIT}.domaim.com"
          traefik.port: '80'
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
  networks:
    proxy:
      external:
        name: '{{ invertory_hostname }}_proxy'
  ```
- Деплоить с docker stack frontend_${git_commit} (gitlab runner)
- Удалять docker stack rm frontend_${git_commit} (после тестирования или merge git hook или удаление ветки)

UPD:

- не проблем с одновременным деплоем множества версий (не забываем про ресурсы сервера)
- если один и тот же git commit - docker обновит stack